# How to increase space for text in UIActivityViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have a UIActivityViewController and the info I would like to share is a string. It is pretty long, though, and is truncated at the end. I really would like the person sharing the string to see the whole information on this screen (shown below), so how can I increase space for the text?

Here is what I have so far:

```
@IBAction func shareButton(_ sender: Any) {
    let text = "Click the link below to download the Tean Bottles App and support the \(basicTeamInfo.text!)!"
            
    let textToShare = [ text ]
    let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: textToShare, applicationActivities: nil)
    activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view 
    
    // present the view controller
    self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Here is the truncated text I was talking about:

[image]

Also I just noticed the typo so ignore that.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There's not much you can customize in `UIActivityViewController`... unless you use some private API, it's most likely not possible to increase space for the text. Also, where is the "link below"?

Comment: @aheze It's not on the App Store yet so I can't really do that yet, but all I need to do is URL(String: "\(the link to the app on the store)") and it will work.
Also if I do use some private API, will it still be allowed on the App Store after?

Comment: No, it won't be allowed on the App Store if you use a private API.